# Show that there exists a point $a \in A$.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove or disprove.

Suppose $A,B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ with $A$ compact. Show that there exists a point $a \in A$ such that: for all $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, there exists $b \in B$ such that $|a - b| \le |x - y|$.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. Let's introduce function $\rho_B(x) = \inf_{b\in B}|x-b|$. Since $|x-b|\ge 0$, $\rho_B(x)\ge0$ too. One can show that this function is continuous.
2. On a compact set $A$, continuous function $\rho_B(x)$ reaches its minimum. So there exists such point $a\in A$, that
   $$ \rho_B(a)=\min_{x\in A} \rho_B(x)$$

Here goes the tricky part. It can be the case, that there are number of possibilities to choose $a$. For some choices the infimum of $\rho_B$ will be reachable (some point $b_a\in B$), and for some not. We always choose $a$ with reachable infimum if such $a$ exists.

On the picture below, both $\rho_B(a_1)=\rho_B(a_2)=\min_{x\in A}\rho_B(x)$. However, for $a_1$ the infimum is unreachable, while for $a_2$ it is otherwise. So we will choose $a_2$ in this case.
[image]

3. If we have reachable infimum $b_a$, then we will always choose it as $b$. For every $x\in A$ and $y\in B$:
   $$
   |a-b| \le |x-y|
   $$
   from definitions of $\inf$ and $\min$.
4. If there is no $a$ with reachable infimum, we can take a sequence $b_n$, so
   $|a-b_n|\to\rho_B(a)$. For every $x$ and $y$, $|x-y| > \rho_B(a)$ (if it's $=$, then $x$ has a reachable infimum and we should have chosen $x$ as a). So there exists such $b_n$, that
   $$
   |a-b_n|-\rho_B(a) < |x-y| - \rho_B(a), \qquad |a-b_n| < |x-y|
   $$

P.S. It's an outline of a proof. You may need to prove all the steps properly. Please ask if something is not clear.

Comment: Why do you point out the things in 1.? How do you know ||≥0 and is it not clear that ()≥0 since we have absolute values in its definition?

Comment: Definition of norm in $\mathbb C$ implies that for every $x$, $|x|\ge 0$. If function $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x$ in  some set, then its $\inf f(x) \ge 0$ too. Should I prove this one?

Comment: Nope, got that part. It makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit  stumped on how to show that function is continuous.

Comment: For two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ and some point $b\in B$ we know that $|x_2-b| \le |x_1-b| + |x_2-x_1|$ (triangle inequality). So for every value in set $S_1=\{|x_1-b|,b\in B\}$ there is a value in $S_2=\{|x_2-b|,b\in B\}$ which lies within $\pm|x_2-x_1|$. Can you see now why $\inf S_1 \to \inf S_2$ when $x_1\to x_2$?

Comment: Got it! Thanks.

Comment: @Vasity Mitch Ok, the tricky part is indeed tricky. The theorem I'm looking at is 4.16 in baby Rudin, and there he uses the $\inf$ instead of the $\min$. So is this what you mean by it might not "reach" the min?

Comment: Oh, but the image of $f$ is closed and bounded, so it is a min.